# Basic Authentication for JIRA-Python no longer works for REST API calls. What next?

Tags: python, rest, authentication, jira, jira-rest-api

In Python, I used to be able to authenticate with JIRA over REST using a simple bit of code:

```
from jira import JIRA

my_JIRA_username = 'my_name'
my_JIRA_pass = 'my_password'
server = {'server': 'https://my_site.atlassian.net'}
jira = JIRA(server, basic_auth = (my_JIRA_username, my_JIRA_pass))
```

And then be able to do something simple like:

```
my_issue = jira.issue('MYISSUE-1')
print my_issue.key
```

But JIRA has changed things, and I am guessing no longer allows basic authentication like this via the REST API.  Instead I get a 401 error.

I tired creating an API token, as suggested here:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html
except I have NO idea where to use it (it doesn't work if I just use it as a password, like in the code above).

I looked into OAuth as an alternative but I cannot find any code that goes from point A to B that makes ANY sense to me.

Instead I find things like this:
https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/atlassian-oauth-examples/src/master/python/app.py

Which is pure gibberish to me.  It can't be that complicated!

Can anyone help with a simple jira-python example of using something other than basic authentication that moves from the initialization to a simple REST call?

It would be most appreciated!  I have months of work that are now useless merely because I can no longer authenticate.

Also, if you can explain how and when to use the API token that JIRA allows you to generate on their cloud instance, that would be appreciated to, as I don't understand that either!

Comment: Your script says "my_JIRA_username" -> have you tried using your email address + api token instead? Because Atlassian has removed usernames from the cloud as well.

Comment: @s.hesse yes, that was the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since using password is already deprecated in basic auth, API tokens are to be used in its place (as you've stumbled upon). In your code you need to use `email` in place of `username` and `apiToken` instead of password. In your code it should be

```
# jira = JIRA(server, basic_auth = (my_JIRA_username, my_JIRA_pass))
jira = JIRA(server, basic_auth = (email, apiToken))
```

Try it out and do tell us how it goes.

Comment: This was the solution!  Thanks.  I was just using the API token and my username so it didn't work.  When I switched to the email address it worked.

Comment: @landspeedrecord in order to help other developers facing the same issue find the answer, feel free to tag this as the solution.

Comment: Hi @Ian, I encounter the same question, but I am using Jira Server v8.16.1, and the answer doesn't work for me. Did you try it on Jira Server as well?

Comment: Hi @skyclouder, for server, you can use the normal username-password pair instead of email and API token.

Comment: Hi @Ian, using email and API token is safer than username and password. ANd Atlassian encourages the use of API tokens. But I don't know how to use it though they provide this function but few sample codes. Did you use API token on the server or cloud version?

Comment: hi @skyclouder, the use of API tokens for basic auth is generally meant for cloud. for server deployments I do not think there's an existing way to generate an API token. Kindly see this server doc https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/basic-authentication/

Comment: Hey @Ian, I'm confused. I have a hosted Jira server and basic token authentication is working fine (as described here: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/basic-auth-for-rest-apis). I can call curl with an authentication header and it works just fine. However, when I try to use the JIRA object, it fails, no matter if I use the user name or email. Any idea how to get token authentication to work on a hosted server?

Answer (score -1):

This answer from atlassian helped me a lot:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-to-use-API-token-for-REST-calls-in-Python/qaq-p/760940

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3.6

# library modules
from jira import JIRA

user = 'me@here.com'
apikey = 'your0api0key0here'
server = 'https://SITE_NAME.atlassian.net'

options = {
 'server': server
}

jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=(user,apikey) )

ticket = 'KRP-11697'
issue = jira.issue(ticket)

summary = issue.fields.summary

print('ticket: ', ticket, summary)
```